# Using "Transform" and "ReplacementTransform" in Manim

Tags: python, transform, manim

I'm new to using manim and I'm trying to use the Transform and ReplacementTransform functions to replace pieces of an equation. When I run the code, the pieces of the equations are overlapping each other.

```
lines1 = Tex('$\\frac{1}{2}$', '$\\divisionsymbol$', '$\\frac{2}{3}$')
lines2 = Tex('$2 \\divisionsymbol 3$')
lines3 = Tex('$\\frac{2}{1} \\times \\frac{1}{3}$'))

        self.play(Write(lines1))
        self.wait(1)
        self.play(Transform(lines[2], lines2))
        self.wait(1)
        self.play(Transform(lines2, lines3))
        self.wait(3)
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it, probably not ideal:

```
from manim import *

class foo( Scene ):
    def construct( self ):

        lines1 = MathTex(r'\frac{1}{2}', r'\divisionsymbol', r'\frac{2}{3}')
        lines2 = MathTex(r'2 \divisionsymbol 3')
        lines3 = MathTex(r'\frac{2}{1} \times \frac{1}{3}')

        lines2.move_to(lines1[2], RIGHT)
        lines2.shift(RIGHT)
        lines3.move_to(lines2)
        self.play(Write(lines1))
        self.play(ReplacementTransform(lines1[2], lines2))
        self.wait(1)
        self.play(ReplacementTransform(lines2, lines3))
        self.wait(3)
```

Note that I've switched to MathTex so that dollar escaping isn't required, and also use raw strings so that double slashing isn't required.

Comment: Thank You! I used a similar method and also used TransformTexMatching class to achieve it but just wanted to verify that I needed to explicitly move pieces of the text itself.